# How to check the data in App Store Connect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I've registered for the Apple Developer Program as an organization.
When I added a new App, I set my developer name into the Company Name field, other data and clicked Create.
This developer name will appear under the app icon after the app is approved for the App Store. But I want to verify the information entered before approval.

Where can I check the data I have entered in the form? the screenshot below explains what info I want to check [screenshot of appstore page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiVaG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no *Company Name* Field, probably because I have an individual account(?), I do not find this field anywhere. But the App Name is located under [Your App] → AppStore → General: App Information.

Answer (score 0):

To check the information you have entered in the Apple Developer Program, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Apple Developer website (developer.apple.com).
2. Sign in with your Apple ID.
3. Click on the "Account" tab in the top menu.
4. Scroll down to the "Organization Information" section and click on the "Edit" button.

This will open a form where you can view and edit the information you have entered for your organization, including your developer name and other details.

Make any necessary changes to the information and click "Save" to update your account.

You can also view the details of your app by going to the "My Apps" section of the Apple Developer website. From here, you can click on the app to view its details and make any necessary changes.